# Reconnect if lost connection to host using TCP - C#

Tags: c#, tcp

If the host goes offline, they lose all connected clients and they don't automatically connect back due to my break; in the code. If I do not do the break; in the code, it mass spams the same user connected over and over. Basically, if the host goes down in the middle of a session, I want the clients to automatically reconnect once the host goes back up.

Here's my code

```
public static void tryConnect()
{
while (true)
 {
  try
         {
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(host), port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    string user = Environment.UserName;
    byte[] userByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user);
    stream.Write(userByte,0,userByte.Length);
    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
    break;
      }
    catch
      {
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a bool out of that function which holds ifno about is client connected or not, if try does not fail it sholud set it to true, or return true to function that called tryConnect, so the one who is reposible for calling tryConect will know that you are connected and you will no more need to try to connect.

If you are just testing connection, than just dont write in the chat that kind of data recives.
Im not sure I understood you question rigth though.